# Presenting login UIViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a need to present a login `UIViewController` within my app when it launches, as well as other points in the workflow, such as when the session times-out and the user needs to re-authenticate.  The important part is that the login view controller be displayed before any other `UIViewController` appears.  I've got my primary UIViewController setup in my Storyboard file as the initial `UIViewController`, and the login `UIViewController` is in a separate `UIViewController` in the `Storyboard`.

I've tried adding a call in my `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidBecomeActive` method to present the login view controller, but I still see the primary `UIViewController` displayed for a brief second.  Is there a better way to handle this scenario?  When a session timeout occurs, it's fine if I present the login `UIViewController` modally over the current view, but for the initial application launch it needs to be the first thing the user sees.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.
I was having the same problem so I created a UIViewController which is identical to the launch screen and if the user needs to authenticate I show the login navigation controller else I show the first UIViewController.